# SLIME and CCL minibuffer documentation in Emacs

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, slime, clozure-cl

When using Emacs, SLIME and Clozure CL I have a minor gripe:
The function signature for `aref` (I have not yet seen any other instances) is shown only as `(aref a)`.

When I go to source the code in question begins with `(defun aref (a &lexpr subs)`. As far as I know, `&lexpr` is not a valid CL lambda list keyword. So this indicates that SLIME does not show the correct function signature due to the "weird" keyword.

But when I do the same for `svref`, say, there is nothing (to me at least) that corroborates the above hypthesis. So maybe SLIME does something, too.

Can anybody point to relevant documentation (I did not find anything relevant in the SLIME manual and in the CCL manual) or does anybody have a workaround/solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SVREF` does not take a list of array indices, since its first argument is a vector. An array might be multi-dimensional, which explains why there are a variadic number of subscripts. For `AREF`, the possible sources are:

```
.../ccl/level-0/l0-array.lisp
  #'AREF
.../ccl/compiler/optimizers.lisp
  (COMPILER-MACRO AREF)
.../ccl/compiler/nx1.lisp
  #'CCL::NX1-AREF
```

Of those, only the first one has the uncommon `&lexpr` keyword in its argument list.

An experiment:

```
CL-USER> (defun foobar (a &lexpr b) (list a b))
;Compiler warnings :
;   In FOOBAR: Unused lexical variable &LEXPR
FOOBAR
```

Let's use the unexported symbol from CCL (auto-completion found it):

```
CL-USER> (defun foobar (a ccl::&lexpr b) (list a b))
FOOBAR
```

This times, it works, let's try it:

```
CL-USER> (foobar 0 1 2 3 4)
(0 17563471524599)
```

*The Evolution of Lisp* says (emphasis mine):

> MacLisp introduced the LEXPR , which is a type of function that takes
>   any number of arguments and puts them on the **stack**;

(see https://www.dreamsongs.com/Files/Hopl2.pdf)

### Fix by substitution

You can fix it at the level of Swank, by replacing `&lexpr` by `&rest`. You only need to patch `ccl.lisp`, which provides an implementation for `arglist` for Clozure:

```
(defimplementation arglist (fname)
  (multiple-value-bind (arglist binding) (let ((*break-on-signals* nil))
                                           (ccl:arglist fname))
    (if binding
        (substitute '&rest 'ccl::&lexpr arglist)
        :not-available)))
```

### More details

In fact, in `swank-arglists.lisp` you can see that the stuff that is unknown is put in a separate list, called `:unknown-junk`. To see it in action, do:

```
CL-USER> (trace swank::decoded-arglist-to-string)
NIL
```

Then, write `(aref` and press <kbd>Space</kbd>, which triggers a query for the argument list and produces the following trace:

```
0> Calling (SWANK::DECODED-ARGLIST-TO-STRING #S(SWANK/BACKEND:ARGLIST :PROVIDED-ARGS NIL :REQUIRED-ARGS (CCL::A) :OPTIONAL-ARGS NIL :KEY-P NIL :KEYWORD-ARGS NIL :REST NIL :BODY-P NIL :ALLOW-OTHER-KEYS-P NIL :AUX-ARGS NIL :ANY-P NIL :ANY-ARGS NIL :KNOWN-JUNK NIL :UNKNOWN-JUNK (CCL::&LEXPR CCL::SUBS)) :PRINT-RIGHT-MARGIN 159 :OPERATOR AREF :HIGHLIGHT (0)) 
<0 SWANK::DECODED-ARGLIST-TO-STRING returned "(aref ===> a <===)"
```

Notice the `:UNKNOWN-JUNK (CCL::&LEXPR CCL::SUBS))` part.
Maybe a better fix is to let Swank learn about `&lexpr`?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The `svref` passage was intended to keep in mind that SLIME/Swank maybe generates the function signatures regardless of how they are defined. But, granted, it did a poor job. I did not know that `&lexpr` was used in earlier Lisps, thanks!

Comment: Also, from your answer I take it, that there is no ready made "solution" for this "problem".